# Java getting the wrong number of jbuttons in grid layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

So I'm new to Java and im definitely new to Swing.

I've got a 80 X 80 array thats going to be used by a maze. I need my gui to have 80 X 80 buttons so they can be tied to the values in my array.

I cant figure out why I'm only getting five or six large buttons from this code. If anyone can tell me how I can get this to work then thank you in advance because I'm stumped.

Just run it and you'll see what I mean...also I guess I've not figured out how to change the color of the buttons and I changed the background color instead.

Heres my code:

```
public static void draw() {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Maze");
    f.setSize(800, 800);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel c = (JPanel)f.getContentPane();
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    c.setLayout(gridLayout);
    for(int i =0;i<80;i++){
        for(int j =0;j<80;j++){
            JButton b = new JButton();
            c.add(b, i,j);
            b.setSize(10, 10);
            b.setOpaque(true);
            b.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `80 * 10 > f.setSize(800, 800);` and your code is not possible to fit in FullHd monitor
2. 2. use `f.pack()` instead of `f.setSize(800, 800);`
3. `f.pack()` and `f.setVisible(true);` (could be a main issue) should be last code lines in non_static and renamed to !`public void DrawMe() {`!, because `draw()` is reserved word for/in Java API
4. `c.add(b, i,j);` should be last code line too (logical ordering),
5. `c.add(b, i,j);` set row and columns for GridLayout instead of injecting the JButton to virtual grid in `GridLayout`

---

- make me some sense (starting with the numbers of elements)

[image]

from

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawMe {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel c = new JPanel();
    private static final int column = 10;
    private static final int row = 10;

    public DrawMe() {
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, column));
        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                JButton b = new JButton((i + 1) + " " + (j + 1));
                c.add(b);
            }
        }
        frame.add(c);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawMe();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting visible and size at the end of the code worked for me, I just have trouble with the order that things should be entered i guess

Comment: If I can sk one more question, now I'm having trouble figuring out painting the buttons,paint and paint component aren't working in my code but I'm trying to pass in b(button) as perimeter. Is that not right.? How should I be doing it if I wanted to paint them all red?

Comment: add there (I removed this code line)  b.setBackground(Color.red); works for me all JButtons are red colored

Comment: That doesn't change anything when i run. If it changes the approach to painting, each button that corresponds to a "w" will be one color, "p" another and, "o" yet another, and I need to repaint the "p" buttons as a mouse moves to them

Comment: and I need to repaint the "p" buttons as a mouse moves to them == use methods from ButtonModel (by using ChangeListener) added to JButton